# Is this time-series problem more a multi-classification or regression problem?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, time-series, regression

I have 188 different drilling datasets with two columns temperature and the target column thermal conductivity respectively. The drilling process includes drilling on four different materials on top of each other.

Each different material has an unique thermal conductivity, so  the target variable can only take one of 4 different values given the four materials.

My question is, what kind of machine learning problem is this?
Is it a regression or multi-classification problem?

Comment: why does nobody help here ?

Comment: I struggled to understand your writing. My suggestion is to be more concise and try breaking the text up in paragraphs or even bullet points if possible.

Comment: i tried editing it now :) maybe now

Comment: What is the problem you want to solve i.e. what are you trying to predict here?

Comment: i try to predict the thermal conductivity with the help of the temperature